# Public Touch Screen Device with Custom System

Tags: device, tablet, touchscreen

For a very long time I've been looking around and seeing those devices like print boxes, ATM's and all kind of devices that are in public and you can use them touchscreen for example. a device at bus station to see BUS stops etc.

I've got an idea lately and since I got no experience with this kind of stuff yet, I would need some help.

1. Where to design and make a custom "tablet"? Would I even need to? (This device would be used in public attached to wall, guess needs some kind of protection?)
2. Which operating system should it be using? (That would handle a program for users to search database and return results).
3. In which programming language could this be coded?

Thanks for all answers in advance! I guess this could get me started.